# One variable "ruining" an otherwise interesting model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, stata

I'm running a logistic regression model with several variables. I'm picking variables with a p less or equal to 0.2 to include in the multivariate model, and a lot of variables have really low p values but there is one categorical variable in which a few of the levels have moderate correlations (p values around 0.1-0.2) so nothing exciting but when I include it in my model, which I have to because I specify the correlation as minimum 0.2, the entire thing breaks apart and nothing is interesting anymore. The p values all becomes mediocre and not significant for the other variables, which were very exciting both on their own and in a multivariate model without that one ruining variable.

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's not easy to tell for sure with the information supplied but it may be multicollinearity.

Comment: Can you tell us what your outcome is, what the categorical is and what the previously significantly associated regressors are? What you describe happens very often in regression models: A variable that is marginally associated with an outcome becomes independent when you add another control. This is an interesting finding that typically makes a lot of sense relative to domain knowledge. Here's one reason this happens: The categorical is a common cause of both the outcome and these other predictors. Another: The categorical is a superior measure of something other predictors also measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote

> I'm picking variables with a p less or equal to 0.2 to include in the
>   multivariate model,

This is known as bivariate screening and it is a terrible method of building a model. This has been discussed here before or see Frank Harrell's book *Regression Modelling Strategies*.

> but when I include it in my model, which I have to because I specify
>   the correlation as minimum 0.2

Correlation or p value?  In either case, you don't "have to".

> The entire thing breaks apart and nothing is interesting anymore. The p
>   values all becomes mediocre and not significant for the other
>   variables, which were very exciting both on their own and in a
>   multivariate model without that one ruining variable.

When a new variable has big effects on the other parameters, that is usually interesting. That is one reason we add control variables. "Ruining" is entirely the wrong word here.  I would look into mediation models.

> Why is this happening?

Without context it's hard to say more than "because your IVs are not orthogonal to each other".

Comment: Well what exactly is a good method of building a model then? I've been told this is a great method and that stepwise selction is terrible.

Comment: Well, what you were told is half-right at any rate!

Comment: Then what IS a good method for building a multivariate logistic regression model? I just get more confused the more I try to get the answer to this question.

Comment: @Paze You probably mean a *multiple* logistic regression model, which is one that has several explanatory variables and one response variable.  It's time to consult a good textbook--Hosmer and Lemeshow, or maybe Agresti--to get a principled start.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I'm a medical student and unfortunately cannot learn statistics entirely, but I do have a statistician at hand that helped me set up the project. Unfortunately he is not directly associated with the project and can not be on call for all questions hence I'm here. Is my model still built badly if it is a multiple regression?

Comment: The best method for building a model is to use substantive knowledge and a priori hypotheses.  If you must use an automated method, LASSO is probably the best of them.

Comment: Peter, in other words you mean only collect data on my hypothesis, so if I hypothesize that headaches may cause seizures, I should only collect two variables, seizure rates and headache rate? And then perhaps some descriptive variables such as age, gender etc?

Comment: Also I should add that I never mentioned the context of my study. It is not to determine a treatment approach for a patient population. It is simply an inquiry study to see if we can find some correlations for further research. Would my methods still be bad practice?